# How can my make my code reusable by using attributes/classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have multiple datasets that I want to do same things on. How can I make my code reusable?

I already grouped some of my code in functions, but how should I integrate all the functions in a class or something, so that every time I read in a DataFrame, I only need to call function

Comment: SO probably isn't the right place for such a general question. You're going to want to come up with a more specific question. I'm not sure why classes would make this any easier for you.

Comment: Because I have multiple datasets that I want to do the same things, but I want to analyze my dataset in different python files. If I do not use class, I think I will need to copy and paste the code for my functions in to a new file every time I analyze a new dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean but, let's say I have a piece of data that I want to import. Each time I import it I want to run the same pre-processing steps, which include lengthy cleaning, data transforms etc.

You could do this maybe:

```
def clean_data():
    pass

def transform_data():
    pass

def import_data():
    data = clean_data(data)
    data = transform_data(data)

data = import_data(data)
```

This can also be turned into a class if it makes more sense.

You have also asked how to use these in different files. Let's say that this script is called "data_import.py".

We can then use it in other scripts (in the same folder) by simply doing

```
import data_import

data_import.import_data(data)
```

or

```
from data_import import *

import_data(data)
```

if it's in another folder you have to add blank file called __init__.py in the same folder that data_import.py is in.

Comment: What if I have multiple functions and want to group them together? If I analyze my data in different python files, what can I do to include the function code only once and call the function when needed

Comment: I just showed you that you can write the functions independently, but call them in 1 function. At the bottom you can see we just ran import_data(data) but it ran multiple functions.

Comment: What I mean is, in that case, if I want to analyze multiple datasets, I have to do it in one file, because my functions are defined in that file. Are there ways (like in C++) to create class maybe, so that even if in different files, I can still use the function without having to type them again?

Comment: You can import modules (such as this file) quite easily in python by simply typing import module_name where module_name is the python file. So for example the script we wrote above if its called "main.py", you can import it in other places by doing import main and then just typing main.import_data(data) wherever you like.

Comment: Basically, if I keep all my functions in main.py, and every time I want to call the function, I can use main.func_name(var) ? Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, I just edited my answer to include an example.

Comment: keep in mind imports can be a pain when the scripts are in different folders, and you may need to use the __init__.py trick. Good luck!